# kernel headers installed but still missing

Tags: kernel, compiling, raspberry-pi, linux-headers, module

I'm working on a RPI2B+ with a fresh install of Raspbian Buster

I want to install https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git so I have to run the following commands :

```
apt update
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) git build-essential dkms -y
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
dkms add .
dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
modprobe 8192eu
```

But dkms needs the linux headers. So I installed `raspberrypi-kernel-headers`. But then when I want to `dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0`, I get the following error :

```
# dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 4.19.75-v7+ cannot be found at
/lib/modules/4.19.75-v7+/build or /lib/modules/4.19.75-v7+/source.
```

The command `apt search linux-headers` returned me some interesting packages so I tried to install : `aufs-dkms` (error while installing), `linux-headers-4.9.0-6-rpi2`, `linux-headers-rpi` and `linux-headers-rpi2`. But it's still not working.

I've tried creating a symlink in `/lib/modules` so the compilation works, but I get an error if I try to modprobe.

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you install `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and `raspberrypi-kernel-headers` both?

Comment: `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` wasn't working so I installed `raspberrypi-kernel-headers`